# How to limit dynamic addition of components within the borders of the form or a panel

Tags: java, swing, size, panel, border

I am trying to add components to a jpanel dynamically from a database, one after the other, however they extend beyond the limits of the form (and even the screen) horizontally. I am using a panel with BoxLayout which positions inner components on the x-axis. What I would like to do is limit the addition of components on the x-axis at the border of the form (or the border of the container panel) . 
What I tried so far is:

- To set the maximum size (width) of the
  container jpanel but that did not
  work.
- To set the layout manager to
  flowlayout, but it also expands
  infinitely on the x-axis.
- To position the container panel inside a
  scrollpane. That makes a huge
  horizontal scrollbar, which means that
  it does not limit the components to
  the border of the form.

Should I make a custom layout? Any ideas simpler than that?
My code looks like:

```
jpanelCases.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.jpanelCases, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
db = Database.getInstance();
List<Category> cats = db.getCategories();
for(Category c : cats){
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            //addition of other components to the newly created panel here
            jpanelCases.add(jp);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that all this happens before the frame is rendered? otherwise, I don't see how adding components to a panel without invoking `revalidate()` would cause them to be rendered "dynamically"

Comment: Yes, the addition happens once at the constructor of the form before the rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however they extend beyond the limits of the form (and even the screen) horizontally.

So what do you want to do in this case:

a) just ignore the components and not add them to the frame
b) display the components on a new line

If the answer is "b", the try the [WrapLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

Comment: I wanted the second case and WrapLayout is working perfectly! For a large number of inner components however a jscrollpane is necessary. In that case it expands at the y-axis, which I think is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 2 glues, one at first one at last:

```
jpanelCases.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.jpanelCases, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

jpanelCases.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

db = Database.getInstance();
List<Category> cats = db.getCategories();
for(Category c : cats){
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            //addition of other components to the newly created panel here
            jpanelCases.add(jp);
}

jpanelCases.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using JScrollPane on the JPanel? This will contain the elements within the panel without exceeding its physical boundaries. Otherwise, if you do not like the scroll idea I suggest that you somehow keep track of the total sum of width of elements added to the panel with respect to the panel physical width, and stop adding elements when the next element width added to the sum exceeds the panel width.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Using JscrollPane introduces a scrollbar on the x-axis, which I think is a little less handy than scrolling on the y-axis.